# How to output multiple error messages when using && operator

Tags: javascript

```
if(isValid(id) && isValid(id2)) {
    //do sth..
}
```

I want to check if id and id2 are valid, if they are not, it will output err messages and return false.

The problem with short-circuit evaluation is that only one err message will be outputted if it is false.

Any ways to output two error messages if they are both false??

Comment: Does `isValid` *only* check whether it's valid or not, or does it *also* show an error message if invalid?

Comment: first set innerText(err message) then return false

Answer (score 0):

Execute them all by hand and count the errors:

```
var errors = 0;
if(!isValid(id)) {
    ++errors;
}
if(!isValid(id2)) {
    ++errors;
}
if(errors > 0) {
    // complain and return
}
// Do whatever needs to be done when everything is valid
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming isValid shows the error message you need to ensure all the method calls happen before the if is evaluated. If you want to keep pretty much the same code structure this is a little bit a of a hack but works. It works by creating an array of all the results then looking for a false item.

```
if([isValid(id), isValid(id2)].indexOf(false) == -1) {
    //all items are valid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstValid = false;
if (isValid(id) && (firstValid=true) && isValid(id2)){
  // do the things for everything is valid
}else if (!firstValid && isValid(id2)){
  // do other things
}
```

or how about

```
var firstValid = false;
if (isValid(id) && (firstValid=true) && isValid(id2) || firstValid && isValid(id2)){
 // do stuff 
}
```

I personally wouldn't recommend doing this or any other one of the tricks shown in actual production code though as short circuit is used to make your code faster.

maybe updating the UI should be done external to the validation check, or maybe there should be a single check for both that updates the correct piece of the UI. I not sure about the full details of your application but I recommend spend a little bit more time to think of why you have the problem rather than the best way to solve it.